# time in Magento

Tags: magento, time

I am dealing with the time in Magento and wanted to see if anyone came across this and can explain it.

2012-01-24 06:35:43 is the created_at stamp for an order placed at Jan 24, 2012 1:35:43 AM Eastern Standard time.

Does this mean that my server is in UTC time and that my Magento saves everything in UTC and converts to Eastern when displaying?

If Magento is converting the value (which I assume to be the case), what is the method/class/helper that handles this?

Comment: Magento (correctly) saves order entities (and possibly all core entities) in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't dug in too deep on this one, but it's my understanding most Magento date/time stuff is handled by the `Mage_Core_Model_Date` class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Date.php
```

It would not surprise me if some modules have their own date handling functions through.  That sort of thing tends to happen in systems as modular as Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Magento stores its internal timestamps as UTC.  Individual stores can be configured with their own timezones by going to System -> Config -> General -> Locale Options.

You can get the adjusted timestamp for a store by doing this:

```
$date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(<store_id>, <utc_timestamp>);
```

This will return a `Zend_Date` object.

You can also get the current timestamp for a store by doing this:

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp(<store_id>);
```

This will return an integer timestamp.